# Sharepoint 2013 via powershell "Install-SPApp : The specified URL is not in the same Site Collection as this App"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

SP2013: I created a SharePoint hosted App (Hello World program) in VS2012. Now to upload/install the app, I tried powershell, Below is powershell commands for installing app:

```
$spapp = Import-SPAppPackage -Path "D:\demoAppSPHosted.app"  -Site "http://spsite:2222/" -Source DeveloperSite 

Install-SPApp -Web "http://spsite:2222/sites/devApp"-Identity $spapp
```

I am not able to pass this hurdle:

> Install-SPApp : The specified URL is not in the same Site Collection as this App

Answer (score 0):

For developer site, you could upload the .app to 'Apps in Testing' directly.

For this case, I think the -Source parameter should be [App catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spapppackage?view=sharepoint-ps).

[Here is sample script for normal installations.](https://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/how-to-install-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell-script-using-server-sharepoint-object-model/)